# Rewrite Rule fro domains in config file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a domain like www.example.com but now this is changed to www.xyz.com

Now I want that if users comes on old domain like http(s)://www.example.com/mypage?query=search

then domain should change to new domain with query string and page.

mean user should redirect to http(s)://www.xyz.com/mypage?query=search

For this what setting i need to do in my web.config file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^www.example.com(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.xyz.com{R:1}" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```